# Passing Extra variable to a hooked function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to pass the $extra variable to the my_function, in wordpress. Is the following the only way (defining global) to do this, or are there any better way to do this.....

```
global $extra;
$extra = 'some value';
do_action( 'save_post','my_function' $post_ID);

function my_function($post_ID) {
    global $extra;

/* other codes here*/
}
```

Comment: Where does the value for $extra come from? Perhaps there's a way to fetch this value inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an array as argument instead. Not the most beautiful way, but it would work.

```
$arg = array('extra'=>'some value', 'post_ID'=>$post_ID);
do_action('save_post','my_function', $arg);

function my_function($arg) {
    $extra = $arg['extra'];
    $post_ID = $arg['post_ID'];

    /* other codes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Define a global variable if the action you are doing is wordpress builtin.
2. If the action is your custom action - you may use `do_action('action_name', $arg1, $arg2)` and `add_action($action_name, $callback_function, $priority, $arg_count)` where `$arg_count` is the number of arguments those are accepted by action handler. `$priority` should be 10 in most cases. Also see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action